# User.all takes 5-10 minutes locally. Request times out to iterate through each

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, sidekiq

I have 233_997 records in the database for Users. It takes over 10 minutes to iterate through this and I need to go through each one to send a job to sidekiq. The server times out before it can create a job for each user. What do I do?

```
User.find_each do |user|
  UpdateMembershipLevelWorker.perform_async(user.id)
end
```

How can I make this request go through without timing out the server? It's the User.find_each part that is very slow... but maybe that's normal with 200k records.

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: Through a controller request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is , have a background process (via sidekiq , since you are already using it) for your users loop.

```
# app/workers/hard_worker.rb
class HardWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  User.find_each do |user|
   UpdateMembershipLevelWorker.perform_async(user.id)
  end 

end
```

*(got copied from the site :) http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/)*

What I normally do in long running processes are, run them in background and writing the status to a db table. So later I could display users about the errors etc..

Comment: So that effectively creates 1 queue for the processing of each User and then fires off yet another queue for the actual update? I can try sticking the find_each in there. Let me try and report back.

Comment: I believe you could have a one background process to do everything, otherwise having 233_997 will not be a good idea :).

Comment: Thank you, this works (i think) will report back if I run into issue. Thank you!

Comment: Just an added note, `#find_each` processes a total of 1000 records each loop or as indicated by a `:batch_size` option http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each